# Taking a preexisting Google map and importing into Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am creating an app for a state trail, this trail is ~200 miles long and has a hundred or so attractions along the way. Here is the preexisting map with all the venues and attractions layed out: https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=z5cNDCbZgqkg.kReB3k9EGYyI

To save time, I want to embed this map into the app. Is there a way to do it using the Google API or should I just use a Web view?

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps API is available and can easily be implemented to address what you need.
It's basically just configuring longitudes and latitudes then setting them on your Maps and Markers implementation using the API.

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(10, 10))
        .title("Hello world"));
}
```

You can check out the Google Maps API [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker#code_samples) to get started.

You can also use the [Google Maps javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial) to implement it into an android app using a `WebViewFragment`.

```
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
    });
}
```

Either way should be fine. It all falls down to what you are more comfortable in using.